vue useRoute function
I am using useRoute() in my Vue.js application. It returns an object if I call the function inside the class, but not when I put it inside @click.
Here is the code:
<script setup>
import { RouterLink, useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const activeRoute = function() {
  const route = useRoute();
  console.log(route);
};
</script>

<template>
  <nav>
    <div>
      <RouterLink
        to="/add/job"
        :class="activeRoute() ? 'text-white' : 'text-black'"
      >
        Add Job
      </RouterLink>
      <RouterLink @click="activeRoute()" to="/jobs">Jobs</RouterLink>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

I tried to use setTimeout to see if the console logging it after 5 seconds would work. However it is still undefined.
I console logged the function useRoute and it shows it returning an inject() function. It is built into Vue.js and may be the reason it only returns an object if run at the right time.

useRoute is misused. The composables are supposed to be used in the body of setup, unless stated otherwise.
It should be:
const route = useRoute();
    
const activeRoute = function() {
  console.log(route);
};

route object is reactive and is updated depending on the current route.

Thank you! It works. Not sure about the theory. Probably something got to do with asynchronous functionality.

If you mean why it couldn't work the way you did this, yes, it's related to async. It depends on the implementation of a particular composable. useRoute relies on provide/inject which relies on component hierarchy, this is expected for any composables that "injects" some global instance. It's possible for Vue to track in which comp inject() is called only when it's called at the time when comp instance is created, i.e. setup and contemporary lifecycle hooks (created, etc)
